# the display of word press theme in preview mode

Tags: local-installation

I want to create a showcase website for company using WordPress and to show the result in local server (using WampServer)  , so I meet the problem when navigating
Appearance-> Customize the front page of website take time to load and at the end browser shows me a problem in access as you see in the image below .I want your helps please and thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should check out C:\wamp\logs and find the PHP logs, it will probably tell you what is happening. I'm guessing PHP will have exhausted its memory on something.